# Nuxtjs Page components are not updated even if the vuex store is updated

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am using nuxtjs for a server side rendering project. I have a REST API from where I would like to update the Vuex store and display the page. [In the nuxtjs documentation for using Vuex store, it mentions using fetch api of the pages](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-fetch-method). So I am trying to fetch the article list for the API and render the page.

Vuex store:

```
const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      article_list: []
    },
    mutations: {
      updateArticleList (state, payload) {
        state.article_list = payload
        console.log('article list length', state.article_list.length)
      }
    },
    actions: {
      mutateArticleList ({commit}, payload) {
        api.get_articles()
          .then((data) => {
            commit('updateArticleList', data)
          })
      }
    }
  })
}
```

In the pages/index.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="update">Update</button>
    <p v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id">Article</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    fetch ({store}) {
      store.dispatch('mutateArticleList')
    },
    computed: {
      articles () {
        return this.$store.state.article_list
      }
    },
    methods: {
      update () {
        this.$store.dispatch('mutateArticleList')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

On the console I can see that the store's article_list has been updated

```
console.log('article list length', state.article_list.length) // 16
```

But on the index.vue page, there's no articles. Even on the console of index `created` method the article_list is 0

```
console.log('index created length', this.$store.state.article_list.length) // 0
```

What am I missing here? Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since vex store are reactive you can retrieve a store's state by returning it within a computed prooperty. See [getting vuex state into components](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html)

what you are doing is:

```
<tag-contents v-for="article in $store.state.article_list" :key="article.id"></tag-contents>
```

instead do this:

```
<template>
  ...
    <tag-contents v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id"></tag-contents>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default  {
    ...
    fetch ({store, params}) {
        api.get_articles()
            .then((data) => {
                store.dispatch('mutateArticleList', data)
            })
    },
    created () {
        console.log('index created length', this.$store.state.article_list.length)
    },
    computed:{
        articles(){
            return this.$store.state.article_list;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

whenever store's state is updated the computed prperty `articles` is reevaluated and cuases the DOM to update

One more things to mention:

Since actions are for asynchronous tasks you can move your RESTapi fetch logic into you `mutateArticleList` action and commit a mutation to update state by passing the data recieved from ajax call as payload to the mutation.

So now your code should be:

**store**

```
const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      article_list: []
    },
    mutations: {
      updateArticleList (state, payload) {
        state.article_list = payload
        console.log('article list length', state.article_list.length)
      }
    },
    actions: {
      mutateArticleList ({commit}, payload) {
          api.get_articles()
            .then((data) => {
                commit('updateArticleList', data);
            })
      }
    }
  })
}
```

**index.vue**

```
<template>
  ...
    <tag-contents v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id"></tag-contents>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default  {
    ...
    fetch () {
        this.$store.dispatch('mutateArticleList', data)
    },

    computed:{
        articles(){
            return this.$store.state.article_list;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! I have updated my question with your code with slight modifications. But still, the page does not update. In the terminal, I can see the total articles, but in the browser the articles length is 0. I have added an extra button to update/dispatch the action to get items from the api. When I click the button, to get the items, then the page gets updated. How can I get the api results and then display the page.

Comment: @Robin try calling the update method in the created() hook and remove all that fetch thing